# Audio Unit to capture sound from mic, add reverb ,then send to speaker

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

Sorry to bother again.

I used the audio graph processing method to play the mic-in and add effect to the sound to the speaker.
When I use the AUGraph_1 : RIO_input->Converter->
AUiPodE->RIO_output, it works fine and I can hear the sound play back.

But when I use the  AUGraph_2 : RIO_input->Converter->
AUReverb2->RIO_output, try to add some reverb, the thing goes wrong,and no sound at all.

here is the log printed by using CAShow:

AUGraph_1>>>
node 1: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x816f920 O I

node 2: 'aufc' 'conv' 'appl', instance 0x81713e0 O I

node 3: 'aufx' 'ipeq' 'appl', instance 0x8171740 O I

Connections:

node   1 bus   1 => node   2 bus   0  [ 2 ch,      0 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x0000000C) 16-bit little-endian signed integer]

node   2 bus   0 => node   3 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000C2C) 8.24-bit little-endian signed integer, deinterleaved]

node   3 bus   0 => node   1 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000C2C) 8.24-bit little-endian signed integer, deinterleaved]

AUGraph_2>>>>

node 1: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x8151420 O

node 2: 'aufc' 'conv' 'appl', instance 0x7539df0 O

node 3: 'aufx' 'rvb2' 'appl', instance 0x7539210 O

Connections:

node   1 bus   1 => node   2 bus   0  [ 2 ch,      0 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x0000000C) 16-bit little-endian signed integer]

node   2 bus   0 => node   3 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]

node   3 bus   0 => node   1 bus   0  [ 2 ch,      0 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x0000000C) 16-bit little-endian signed integer]

Is there something wrong?

Please help me with this, any clue will be great appreciated.

Best

Answer (score 2):

I did the same exercise but used a mixer unit instead of a converter as follows

AudioUnitGraph 0x13D000:
  Member Nodes:
    node 1: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x7ac9100 O
    node 2: 'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl', instance 0x7acdee0 O
    node 3: 'aufx' 'rvb2' 'appl', instance 0x7acf150 O
  Connections:
    node   1 bus   1 => node   2 bus   1  [ 1 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000C2C) 8.24-bit little-endian signed integer, deinterleaved]
    node   2 bus   0 => node   3 bus   0  [ 2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000029) 32-bit little-endian float, deinterleaved]
    node   3 bus   0 => node   1 bus   0  [ 2 ch,      0 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x0000000C) 16-bit little-endian signed integer]

I simplified the code from Audiograph http://zerokidz.com/audiograph/Home.html to do this as it is very well commented and explains the gotchas concerning the various ASBD formats.